# C# SoundPlayer.Play() is delayed once

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to add a chime to my C# application. The idea is that the chime will sound when a timer hits 3, 2, 1, 0. However, there is a delay the first time the sound is played so instead of a an even tempo-ed "beep, beep, beep, ding!" I get "be-beep, beep, ding!"

The sound file is a .wav in resources and I play the file like this

```
//The constructor of the class that plays the file
public ViewPage() {
    ...
    
    this._chimePlayer = new(Properties.Resources.Chime);
    this._chimePlayer.Load();
}

// The actual usage
internal void OnTick()
{
    ...
    if ( this.TimeRemaining < this._nextChime )
    {
        this._nextChime -= 1000;
        this._chimePlayer.Play();
    }
}
```

I *thought* that using the `SoundPlayer.Load()` function would preload the sound file into memory... but it has had zero effect on the delay.

Once the sound has been played a single time, no matter when or where I play the sound file in my application, it works exactly as expected until I close the program. I just can't get that first chime to sound on time. It's off by a solid 500ms or more (which is unacceptable when the chime is supposed to indicate a countdown.)

The timer resets at zero and counts down again and every iteration after that first works perfectly. How can I ***force*** the resource into memory as a pre-load?

I've tried using the `SoundPlayer.Load()` method ahead of time and I event went so far as trying `MemoryStream.CopyTo(Stream)` method on the resource to copy it to a new memory stream.

Comment: Judging from past questions `SoundPlayer` creates more headaches than it solves and some use NAudio instead; however, have you tried playing a dummy mute sound first?

Comment: I'm currently working on the assumption that it's a resource loading thing because (from what I've read in a couple places) resources aren't loaded into memory until they're actually used? I haven't tried the dummy file so that's a possibility and I was hoping to avoid NAudio. Adding an extra package/library to play a simple chime seems like overkill.

Comment: Well, there goes that theory. I copied the bytes into a byte array and created a new memory stream from the byte array (and verified the data in debugger)... So it's a SoundPlayer problem. Nice.

Comment: So the delay is gone playing from a memory stream rather than a file?

Comment: @Ray No, it didn't fix it. I just bit the bullet and added NAudio. I really didn't want to use an entire library for 4 lines of code but the results matter more than the means I guess.

Comment: Maybe this helps you? There is no accepted answer but details in the ones given  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414271/how-to-play-audio-file-in-c-sharp-with-low-latency-very-little-delay-in-c

Comment: Compare to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900461/slow-start-for-avaudioplayer-the-first-time-a-sound-is-played), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739596/small-delay-when-playing-a-sound-for-the-first-time-with-spritekit), [3](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/first-time-sound-play-delayed/257204).  Nothing to do with .net, when sounds overlap it is the backend that is slow.  Audio driver, anti-malware, disk, etc.  Try another machine.  A "splash" sound played at program startup is a simple workaround.

Comment: @HansPassant Using NAudio fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using NAudio in the end.

```
private WaveStream _chimeStream = new WaveFileReader(Properties.Resources.Chime);
private WaveOut _chimePlayer = new();

public ViewPage()
{
    ...
    _chimePlayer.Init( _chimeStream );
}

internal void OnTick()
{
    ...
    if ( this.TimeRemaining < this._nextChime)
    {
        this._nextChime -= 1000;
        this._chimeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        this._chimePlayer.Play();
    }
}
```