# C# play sound instantly

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

Is there a way to play a notification sound as fast as a button click? I feel like there is a delay of a few hundred milliseconds!

I'm using this:

```
public void btn_Click(object sender, eventargs e)  
{
    playExclamation();  
}

public void playExclamation()  
{    
    SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78136634/17034

Answer (score 0):

You can try achieve lower latency by using the SoundPlayer class from the System.Media namespace, which is part of the .NET Framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer